# Sagemath -- finding Eigenvalues of a matrix representation of a tensor

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-physics, tensors, general-relativity, sagemath

I am using sagemath to compute Einstein tensors of a non-standard spacetime. The output is something horrid and non-diagonal. I need to find the Eigenvalues of this tensor... which is represented as a symbolic matrix. This is proving to be non-trivial with the sagemath documentation.

Is there a way to convert my tensor output into a matrix that sagemath can find the eigenvalues for?

If a worked example is required, please let me know as I can provide an update easily.

Thanks in advance...